# how to match regex in bash script with for loop?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm trying to match multiple strings from output of a command and do something for each one of them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'Howdy, can you please give me the domain (without www)?'
read domain
routes=$(flynn -a shop-app route | grep $domain)
# echo $routes | egrep "http\/\S+"

pattern="http\/[^ ]+"
for word in $routes
do
    [[ $word =~ $pattern ]]
if ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
then
    match="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    sed -i s/DOMAIN/$domain/g $domain.sh
    sed -i s:ROUTE1:$match:g $domain.sh

fi

if ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
then
    match2="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    sed -i s:ROUTE2:$match2:g $domain.sh

fi

done

echo $match
```

update: the regex part works now but the loop is not working. I know the loop will find two match and want to do something with each one

the sample text:

```
http:www.lipi.ir            shop-app-web  http/d49ced12-c6ca-46a0-b919-6d97b6580ad3  false   false   / 
http:lipi.ir                shop-app-web  http/ff919e9d-9bf7-4342-a4b3-ea184c698959  false   false   /
```

Comment: If someone says to you something "is not working" what's the first thing you would ask?

Comment: I'd ask why it's not working

Comment: looks overcomplicated and redundant

Comment: No you wouldn't, you'd likely ask for details since "is not working" is extremely vague

Comment: I see. did not post the text it matches against. will edit

Comment: `\S` doesn't work with BASH regex, use `[^[:space:]]`

Comment: that fixed regex issue. but I still can't use both matches to do something. my regex loop is to blame?

Comment: Condition should be just `if `[[ $word =~ $pattern ]]` No need to use `if ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` or `if ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`